# How to increase MiniTest timeout threshold?

Tags: ruby, testing, timeout, minitest, executiontimeout

I'm switching to MiniTest for a gem of mine and getting a `Timeout::Error` for certain examples. Due to some external deps, when I request a connection against the server, it's being returned after a few seconds, this causes that exception.

Is there a way to increase the timeout threshold for each example?

Comment: Can you provide some example code demonstrating your problem?